# Access an activity from a fragment in a fragment that's loaded via XML

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity contains a fragment A that's embedded via XML, which contains fragment B that's embedded also embedded via XML.

When I call B.getActivity() I get none returned. Is there a straightforward way to access the activity from B?

Comment: you want activity method access?

Comment: please make sure you are calling getActivity in or after onAttach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit of a non-answer, but trying to control your activity from your Fragment is a bad practice.

If you need to reference the activity to get the context or something then you just use `getActivity()` within the fragment. If you reference the class via `B.getActivity()` it will be null since you're not looking at an instance of the class, but the class construct. Since the Activity isn't attached until the Fragment is created (even if this happens in XML), referencing `ClassName.getActivity()` won't give you anything. So just call `getActivity()` to get to it.

The best way to handle communication between Fragments and Activities is to use interfaces and callbacks to send specific information. You shouldn't be controlling your app from the Fragment, the Activity should be doing that. You should only need to send small pieces of information from your Fragment back to your parent Activity.

Example: In your Fragment:

```
 private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

 @Override 
 public void onAttach(Context context) { 
     super.onAttach(context); 
     if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) { 
         mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context; 
     } else { 
         throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() 
                 + " must implement OnEDHGameStartListener"); 
     } 
 }

//the way to pass information here. Can use return values if you'd like
//this is what the activity needs to implement
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void thingHappened(String theInformation);
}

//when that thing happens that you want to communicate you call back to the 
//activity like so:
public void someAction() {
    mListener.thingHappened("the information");
}
```

In your Activity, you implement `MyFragmentClass.OnFragmentInteractionListener` and then you can handle the information passed between the two by overriding the method.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
// most of the code here...

    //now implement the listener.
    @override 
    public void thingHappened(String information){
        //what you want the activity to do with the information
    }
}
```